# How to call a stored procedure with two parameters using Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, stored-procedures

Please I want to call a stored procedure with two parameters using Spring MVC and Hibernate.

The code in my model is this one:

```
 @NamedNativeQuery(name="callprocLogin", query = "{CALL procLogin (:username, :password)}",  callable = true, resultClass =SubscriberLogin.class)
```

and my DAO method is

```
public SubscriberLogin getUserAndPassword(String username, String password) {   
        
    //Using Stored Procedure
    List<String> param = new ArrayList<String>();
    param.add(username);
    param.add(password);
    List<SubscriberLogin> list =null;
    list = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("callprocLogin", "username,password", param);       
    return list.get(0);
}
```

Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Last time I wasted time trying to use Nhibernate to call stored procs, I ended up using ADO.NET. Much easier, and easier to understand.

Comment: findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(String queryName, String[] paramNames, Object[] values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related to how you send the parameter arguments.

Instead of:

```
list = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("callprocLogin", "username,password", param);
```

you should have:

```
list = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(
    "callprocLogin", 
    new String[] {"username", "password"}, 
    new Object[] {username, password}
);
```

Comment: Vlad Mihalcea answer was very useful.. Thanks a lot